# Visual Studio remote debugging via ssh: "key exchange validation failed"

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, remote-debugging

I got this error message on starting remote debugging a .net core application running on Linux. "key exchange validation failed"
I am using SSH with authentication type Password.

Answer (score 15):

The solution:

- go to menu Debug->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager
- select the corresponding device you want to debug
- click the Edit button
- provide your credentials and click the Connect-Button.

Now you should get a remote debugging connection to your device.

Comment: the problem is that it VS shows this problem every time you rebot the system.
Today, in 17.8.5 version you need to manual click "verify" in connection manager, It's not intuitive or convenient
I'm looking for a way to get around this but still no results